# Show that $\gcd(2^m+3^m,2^{m+1}+3^{m+1})=1, \forall{m}\in\mathbb{N}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I tried showing that there must exist $s,t\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $s(2^m+3^m)+t(2^{m+1}+3^{m+1})=1$, but had no success.

Answer (score 3):

Since \begin{align}
3^{m+1}+2^{m+1} &= 2(3^m+2^m)+3^m,\\
\end{align}
we have
\begin{align}\gcd(3^{m+1}+2^{m+1},3^m+2^m) &=\gcd(3^m+2^m,3^m)\\
&=\gcd(3^m, 2^m)\\
&=1\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Note that$$3\times(3^m+2^m)=3^{m+1}+3\times2^m=3^{m+1}+2^{m+1}+2^m.\tag{1}$$So let $p$ be a prime number that divides both $3^m+2^m$ and $3^{m+1}+2^{m+1}$. It is clear that $p$ cannot be $2$ (these numbers are odd). But it follows from $(1)$ that $p\mid 2^m$ and therefore that $p=2$.